# Listing ToC in Itself As Part, Not Section

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script, parts

I'm writing a LaTeX document (scratcl) and am using *\part* as my highest level. I also need my ToC listed in itself. I've included *\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}*, but this lists the ToC as a section of the part before it, not a part on its own, e.g., my ToC and PDF bookmarks look like

- Title Page *(part)*
- Document Revision History *(part)*

  - Contents *(section belonging to* Document Revision History *)*
- First Section *(part)*
- ...

I've studied the answers in [Change ToC Level of ToC, LoF, and LoT](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397413/change-toc-level-of-toc-lof-and-lot), but they don't seem to address *raising* the ToC level but rather *lowering* it, which is the exact opposite of what I need.

Can someone point me in the correct direction to use *\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}* making the ToC a *part*, not a *section*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but shouldn't something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{My Aweseome TOC}` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `\deftocheading` but then you don't need `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}`:

Is below the kind of thing you're after?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\begin{document}

\part{A preliminary part}

\part{Another preliminary part}

\deftocheading{toc}{\part*{#1}\addtocentrydefault{part}{}{#1}}
\tableofcontents

\part{My first part}
\section {My first section}
\subsection{My first subsection}

Some text.

\subsection{My next subsection}

Some more text.

\part{My second part}
\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!